# How to handle repeated texts in Angular i18n translation

Tags: angular, internationalization, angular8, angular-i18n

I am using angular 8 and i18n to translate a web application from English to Dutch. All the things are working fine. But i had a scenario that, a element `<h4>Customer details</h4>` is presented in `customer-details.component.html`, `customer-form.component.html` and `users.component.html`. In `users.component.html`, the same text `Customer details` is present in two times. I give `i18n` like `i18n="Details of customer @@customerDetailsDetails"`, `i18n="Details of customer @@customeFormsDetails"`. Now in `messages.xlf1` file the same text `Customer details` is presented three times for translation. How can i handle these type of translation repetation ? Help me please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just give the same text and @@id in all your templates

```
i18n="Details of customer @@customerDetails
```

If you give a different ID, the translation will be there multiple times, even if the text is the same